# How to keep data together in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

i have a spreadsheet in excel 2016 that uses the following formulae

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Attending!$A$2:$A$20,AGGREGATE(15,6,(ROW($A$2:$A$20)-ROW($A$2)+1)/(Attending!$B$2:$B$20="Yes"),ROW(1:1))),"")
```

This formula takes names in column `A` of the attending sheet and if column be against those names is set to "Yes" they show in the menu choices sheet.

but it only adds entries into column `A` of menu choices sheet

so then in the destination sheet entries against these peoples name in columns `B`, `C` and `D` get out of wack of someone else gets added above them.

how do I link a given persons `B`, `C` and `D` data to them so they stay in alignment when new entries are added in above them.?

Also when menu choices `B1` has a value greater than empty I want attending sheets `C1` to be set to a value of "Yes".

how do I do these things?

Comment: You should clean up your question with complete sentences and code formatting.

Comment: sample data, current output, where went wrong, and expected output please.

Comment: Here is a video outlining my query and the issues i am having. https://www.loom.com/share/5a36c45693f8407881717d79e07edced

Comment: A better approach would be switching Column A and B on your attending sheet with Column A on your menu sheet, so you determine whether a person is attending on the menu sheet, and select the menu choices on that sheet. On your attending sheet column A will return the names of attendees, and all the subsequent columns can do the calculation based on certain formula, and you manually select if the deposit is paid or not. (Please use @TerryW when responding to my comment otherwise I may miss out your response)

Comment: @TerryW okay so what would the formulas need to be to achieve this?

Comment: would you like to share a link for a sample workbook on google sheet for instance so I can demonstrate what I mean?

Comment: @TerryW here’s the link to the sample file https://1drv.ms/x/s!As7kxm6mCNBnjdgM9S_MN1B-VsUJaQ?e=Hqss5e

Answer (score 1):

From the sample worksheet you provided, I can see that you have switched the columns as suggested. After checking the workbook, I think you should also add the **Deposit** column on the `Menu` Sheet and manually update the column on that sheet.

So presume you have filled out the `Menu` table as below:

[image: Menu Sample]

Enter the following formula in Cell `B2` in your `Attending` table, and drag it across to Column D and drag it down to the end of the table.

```
=IFERROR(IF(VLOOKUP($A2,Table2,COLUMN()+1,0)>0,"Yes","No"),"")
```

And enter the following formula in Cell `G2` in the `Attending` table, and drag it down to the end of the table.

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,Table2,6,0),"")
```

Please note **Table2** in the above formulas are the name for the table on your `Menu` sheet. Please replace it with the actual table name if needed.

Once done, you should have the following on `Attending` sheet:

[image: Attending Sample]

Let's say later on you need to update the `Menu` table for **AMC** as below:

[image: Menu updated]

Your `Attending` table should be updated automatically as below:

[image: Attending updated]

**---------------- EDIT #2 ----------------**

As requested, I have changed Column F on the `Menu` Table to **Amount Paid** instead of **Deposit**, which allows the user to input the actual dollar value paid instead of the word Paid/Unpaid.

[image: Menu Updated2]

Then replace the formula in Cell G2 and H2 on the `Attending` Table as below, and drag them down to the last row of the table.

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,Table2,6,0),"")

=IF([@[Price:]]="","",F2-G2)
```

Then you should have the **Amount Paid** and **Balance to Pay** showing correctly on the `Attending` Table. It may not be necessary to maintain a separate column showing whether a fixed deposit is paid or not as long as it is not mandatory to pay a fixed amount up front.

[image: Attending Updated]

> Conclusion, it is A good practice to keep all manually updated data in one place, and keep all formula-driven data in another. Do not mix them up so you will not encounter the problem of hard-coded data entry does not match with formula-driven result.

Comment: thanks that's great. however last little thing is if they pay the whole value of the meal up front i want to record the extra payment in column G of menu choices and using vlookup sync to column I of attending sheet so as to keep the structure of all manual data in 1 sheet and all auto data in another.

but then in column J of attending show balance left to pay - amount paid but not show errors if amount paid is blank.

Comment: @StuartBennett Please see my **EDIT #2** which has replaced the `Deposit` column with `Amount Paid` so user can input the actual dollar value paid, which will be looked up in the `Attending` table. Btw I wonder if you are able to write such a complicated formula in Column A to look up the attendees distinctively, why can't you work out the IF and VLOOKUP formula for the rest of the columns? If there is someone helped you write the formula in Column A, why couldn't you ask him or her to also update the formulas in the other columns?